# Translation of Fortinet configuration

Tags: security, firewall

We have a small case of security breach in one of our sites, we have a contractor that is suppose to stay out of our firewall Fortinet, today i noticed these two paragraphs that look fishy. My site network administrator bailed on us few months ago and i am trying to wrap my head around these paragraphs without the need of paying someone to do it. I need your help experts!

```
> edit "Mycompany_to_Contractor"
>         set vdom "root"
>         set type tunnel
>         set snmp-index 6
>         set interface "wan1"
>     next
>     edit "Mycompany to Contractor2"
>         set vdom "root"
>         set type tunnel
>         set snmp-index 8
>         set interface "wan1"
>     next
```

Any explanation would be appreciated!

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

These snippets from the `config interface` section of a FortiOS config file show two virtual IPsec tunnel interfaces. When you create an IPsec config, these virtual interfaces are set up so that you can use them in policies to allow/filter traffic to or from the tunnel to any local interface.

The tunnel definition is kept in `config vpn ipsec phase1-interface` and starts with `edit "Mycompany_to_Contractor"`. In this phase1 part you can see the IP address of the remote gateway which may give you a clue to whom the tunnel is connecting to.

The rest of the VPN definition, including local and remote subnets, is defined in `config vpn ipsec phase2-interface`.

To quickly disable remote access from these two contractors / remote sites, disable the policies referring to the tunnel interfaces. Without policy the tunnels cannot be established. For forensic purposes I would backup the config first.